# Get specific properties from objects in a ListBox

Tags: c#, listbox

This is a C# winform project where I have "Car" objects that I am adding to a ListBox. I can add the objects and even see the properties one by one using something like this:

```
Car car = (Car)listBox1.SelectedItem;
Console.Write(car.Name);
```

But how can I get, for instance, the BodyColor property from all cars? I attempted to use foreach with no success. It simply returned the name of the Class for each loop instead of a specific property. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code thus far:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace string_test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Car car1 = new Car();
            car1.Name = "Bobs Car";
            car1.BodyColor = Color.Black;
            car1.IsSedan = true;
            car1.TopSpeed = 110;

            Car car2 = new Car();
            car2.Name = "Bills Car";
            car2.BodyColor = Color.Red;
            car2.IsSedan = false;
            car2.TopSpeed = 140;

            listBox1.Items.Add(car1);
            listBox1.Items.Add(car2);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        // Here is where I am trying to get all BodyColor properties 
        // from every car in the ListBox. 
        // What I have below gets the BodyColor from whatever 
        // car is selected instead.

        Car car = (Car)listBox1.SelectedItem;
        Console.Write(car.BodyColor);
        }

        class Car
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int TopSpeed { get; set; }
            public bool IsSedan { get; set; }
            public Color BodyColor { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return Name;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using either LINQ queries or LINQ methods for something like this. FYI, in case you don't know what LINQ is, it enables you, as a programmer, to make equivalent calls that could be in SQL queries, on C# structures that implements the interface IEnumerable. More on this [here](https://www.google.ca/search?q=LINQ&oq=LINQ&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i65j69i59j0l3.737j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

**LINQ METHODS**

```
var carsFromBodyColor = listbox.Items.Where(obj=> obj!= nulll).Cast<Car>().Select(castedCar => castedCar.BodyColor);
foreach(var c in carsFromBodyColor)
    Console.WriteLine(c.BodyColor);
```

**LINQ QUERIES**

```
var carColors = from Car carItem in listBox.Items
           where carItem != null 
           select carItem .BodyColor;
foreach(var color in carColors)
     Console.WriteLine(color);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use listbox.Items to get all items.
Use LINQ Cast and Select to get list of BodyColors:

```
listBox1.Items.Cast<Car>().Select(c => c.BodyColor);
```

Comment: do you have an example of this in action?